# Receiving conn busy on different queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have a general question about golang and performing queries. I am using gin-gonic as my http framework and pgx driver to perform different queries. I'm running into a problem that some queries return `conn busy` and need to know how to solve this problem for future references. Note some of my queries use `pgx.Conn` and others `pgx.Pool` I have also configured my `pgx.Pool` to have a max 10 connection pools.

An example query I have is

```
SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,email,users.username,dob,country,is_verified, bio,"+
            "profile_json, tier, casual_games, stream_time, profile_image,"+
            "is_streaming, users.created_at FROM users INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.username = users.username WHERE users.user_id = $1
```

Comment: maybe you should reword your question to a more specific one. e.g. show some codes. i guess it's something to do with slow sql query

Answer (score 1):

> Note some of my queries use pgx.Conn and others pgx.Pool

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#Conn

Conn is a PostgreSQL connection handle. It is not safe for concurrent usage. Use ConnPool to manage access to multiple database connections from multiple goroutines.

Seems like your code must be breaking due to use of non threadsafe Conn